# CSS: '+' selection operator not working

Tags: html, css

The background color of the span does not change after the radio button is changed as it should.

Why is this happening? How to fix it?

```css
div {
  margin: 0 0 0.75em 0;
}
.formgroup input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}
input[type="radio"],
label {
  color: brown;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}
input[type="radio"],
label span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 19px;
  height: 19px;
  margin: -1px 4px 0 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
input[type="radio"],
label span {
  background-color: brown;
}
  

input[type="radio"]:checked + p + span{
     background-color:orange;
}
input[type="radio"] + span,
input[type="radio"]:checked + span {
  -webkit-transition:background-color 0.4s linear;
  -o-transition:background-color 0.4s linear;
  -moz-transition:background-color 0.4s linear;
  transition:background-color 0.4s linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <section class="artistpage">
    <div class="search">
      <h1>Artist Directory</h1> 
    </div>
    <ul class="artistlist">
      <li class="artist cf">
        <div class="info">
          <label class="formgroup">
            <input type="radio">
            <span></span>Op1
            <span></span>Op2
            <span></span>Op3
          </label>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Whichever radio option I choose, the first one always gets selected.

Comment: `input` is inside a `label` and so it is **not a sibling** of the other label.

Comment: Side note, you didn't close your section element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your radio button group isn't really the way it is supposed to be. I would suggest you alter that.

```
<ul class="artistlist">
  <li class="artist cf">
    <div class="info">
      <label class="formgroup">
        <input type="radio" name = "op"><span></span>Op1
        <input type="radio" name = "op"><span></span>Op2
        <input type="radio" name = "op"><span></span>Op3
      </label>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is your direct sibling selector.

```
input[type="radio"]:checked + span {
     background-color:orange;
}
input[type="radio"] + span,
input[type="radio"]:checked + span {
  -webkit-transition:background-color 0.4s linear;
  -o-transition:background-color 0.4s linear;
  -moz-transition:background-color 0.4s linear;
  transition:background-color 0.4s linear;
}
```

**Updated with your new query below.**

You'd better use the general sibling selector  `~`

```css
div {
  margin: 0 0 0.75em 0;
}
.formgroup input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}
input[type="radio"],
label {
  color: brown;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}
input[type="radio"],
label span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 19px;
  height: 19px;
  margin: -1px 4px 0 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
input[type="radio"],
label span {
  background-color: brown;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked ~ span {
     background-color:orange;
}
input[type="radio"] + span,
input[type="radio"]:checked span {
  -webkit-transition:background-color 0.4s linear;
  -o-transition:background-color 0.4s linear;
  -moz-transition:background-color 0.4s linear;
  transition:background-color 0.4s linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <section class="artistpage">
    <div class="search">
      <h1>Artist Directory</h1> 
    </div>
    <ul class="artistlist">
      <li class="artist cf">
        <div class="info">
          <label class="formgroup">
            <input type="radio">
            <span></span>Op1
          </label>
          <label class="formgroup">
            <input type="radio">
            <span></span>Op2
            <span></span>Op2.1
            <span></span>Op2.2
            <span></span>Op2.3
          </label>

        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It works for one element. But when I have multiple spans in my radio group, it always selects the first one.

Comment: What if the structure of the radio group itself was changed with all the radio inputs having the same name? Wouldn't that be a simpler solution?

Comment: Yes it would @MadhuGNadig